# How to display all the Table columns in the Azure Databricks base on the Data Base Name?

Tags: python, azure-databricks

> I am trying to display all the table columns in the azure
>   databricks using python. I faced one issue, i was getting only top 20
>   rows. But I need all the tables with columns present in the particular
>   database. Please anyone can tell approach for this. Code is in below.\

Code:

```
Table_name = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES FROM default")
Table_name=Table_name.select('tableName').collect()
mvv_array = [(row.tableName) for row in Table_name]
cnt = 0
for idx,i in enumerate(mvv_array):
  if cnt == 0:
    tmp = spark.sql('DESCRIBE default.'+i).withColumn('table_name',lit(i))
    temp_df = tmp
    cnt = cnt + 1
  else:
    tmp = spark.sql('DESCRIBE default.'+i).withColumn('table_name',lit(i))
    temp_df=temp_df.unionAll(tmp)
temp_df.show()
```

> This approch is suggested by @SohelReza, Thanks to Sohel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `display(temp_df)` instead of `temp_df.show()`
Thanks for your code.it was very helpful for me.